# Dropwizard/Jersey - switch from InMemoryTestContainer to Grizzly

Tags: web-services, jersey, grizzly, dropwizard, servlet-container

**Background:**

According to this issue http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-623, InMemoryTestContainer won't be able to support resource with injectable constructor. So if you have, say, HttpServletRequest injected in your resource class, you will need other test containers, such as grizzly.

**My case:**

I am using dropwizard which is running Jersey underneath, I have HttpServletRequest injected in my resource class like this:

```
@Context HttpServletRequest request;
```

my test class looks like:

```
import com.yammer.dropwizard.testing.ResourceTest;
public class MyResourceTest extends ResourceTest {
    // all the tests go here
}
```

**Question:**

How to switch the test container from InMemoryTestContainer to grizzly?

Answer (score 1):

I've not had to do this myself, but this [gist might be of some help](https://gist.github.com/3016987).

The relevant parts are the use of

`new JerseyTest(new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory())`

and the inclusion of

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-grizzly2</artifactId>
  <version>1.12</version>
</dependency>
```

In the `pom.xml`.

Comment: the gist works still with old version of dropwizard, we are running dropwizard 6 now. I tried to play around with GrizzlyResourceTest gist, no luck yet.

Comment: Yeah, DW moves at a fast pace.

Comment: But even dropwizard 0.6.1 still has this issue.

Comment: Adding the jersey-test-framework-grizzly2 maven dependency seems to cause Jersey to pick up the grizzlywebtestcontainerfactory automatically (it is the default after all), however the DW ResourceTest constructs a "LowLevelAppDescriptor" which is apparently incompatable with a WebTestContainerFactory.  That is basically gibberish to me, but I'd love to find out if it's possible to construct such a JerseyTest with DropWizard infastructure (DropWizard config is too low level?).